# How can I convert PDF Files to TIFF files with compression (Group 4 compression)

Tags: python-imaging-library

I am trying to complete a task to convert PDF's to TIFF files with CCITT t.4 compression. I am using the PymuPDF library/Pillow. From the code below, I am can generate the TIFF files fine, but I can't seem to add the compression to them no matter what I try. Anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

```
import fitz
import os

mat = fitz.Matrix(300 / 72, 300 / 72)  # sets zoom factor for 300 dpi
doc = fitz.open(r"C:\testtiff4\test.pdf")

page_count = doc.pageCount

for page in range(0, page_count):
    page_load = doc.loadPage(page)
    pix = page_load.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)
    img_filename = os.path.join(r"C\testtiff4", "page-%04i.tiff" % page_load.number)
    pix.pil_save(img_filename, format="TIFF", dpi=(300,300), compression="group4")
```

When running the above code, I get the error:

> OSError: encoder error -2 when writing image file

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `libtiff` installed in order to write Group4 compressed files. Check like this:

```
python -m PIL
```

**Sample Output**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Pillow 8.0.1
Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52)
   [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL
Binary modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok, compiled for 8.0.1
--- TKINTER support ok
--- FREETYPE2 support ok, loaded 2.10.4
--- LITTLECMS2 support ok, loaded 2.10
--- WEBP support ok, loaded 1.1.0
--- WEBP Transparency support ok
--- WEBPMUX support ok
--- WEBP Animation support ok
--- JPEG support ok, compiled for 9.0
--- OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support ok, loaded 2.3.1
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok, loaded 1.2.11
--- LIBTIFF support ok, loaded 4.1.0
*** RAQM (Bidirectional Text) support not installed
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT (Quantization method) support not installed
--- XCB (X protocol) support ok
```

---

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for the response. I seem to be getting the below error when running pip install libtiff. Do you know of any way around this?

No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
    CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[999] : testing flags (/O2)
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Thanks,

Comment: I don't use Windows I'm afraid. It looks like you'd have to install the MC Visual C++ stuff -  or do you have it? You can ask another question (they are free), maybe just tagged `[windows]` and `[libtiff]`  and see if anyone knows how to install `libtiff` on Windows, or Google for a while.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Just a question, should this pip install work on linux systems or if i'm running this code through a docker container?

Comment: I have never installed it on Windows. I think it is not really a Python/pip type of thing. I think it's written in C/C++ and it will need to be installed with `cmake` something like here https://yushulx.medium.com/building-libtiff-with-libjpeg-on-windows-dbf544ef603e