# Can't open a 16-bit .tif image from s3 bucket as a BytesIO object

Tags: image, amazon-s3, tiff, gdal, bytesio

I have a 16-bit .tif sitting in my s3 bucket. I can bring it down as a BytesIO object, but I don't want to save it locally because it's large and I have to do this in a loop with many images. With a typical 8-bit .png, I could simply use PIL's Image.open(myBytesObject). But this method doesn't work with my 16-bit .tif. I know I can use skimage.io.imread() or gdal.Open() to open 16-bit tifs, but I can't figure out how to get it to work without downloading the full file locally. See below for code and errors. Ultimately, I'm trying to turn the .tif into a numpy array for computer vision stuff down the line...

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
              aws_access_key_id=access_id,
              aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
              region_name=region_name)

myBytesObject = BytesIO()
s3.download_fileobj(bucket_name, tif_name, myBytesObject)

# try opening it now...
myBytesObject.seek(0) # <--- this trick didn't work
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(myBytesObject).convert('RGB')._repr_png_()
```

Gives the error:

```
UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fb8339f4fe0>
```

When I try using skimage...

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread(myBytesObject)
```

I get the error:

```
KeyError: (b'II', 1, (1,), 1, (16, 16, 16, 16), (0, 0, 0))
SyntaxError: unknown pixel mode
```

When I use gdal.Open(), I can successfully get it to load but the FileFromMemBuffer() function below downloads a local copy, which I'm trying to avoid...

```
vsipath = '/vsimem/'+tif_name
myBytesObject.seek(0)
gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(vsipath, myBytesObject.read())
gimg = gdal.Open(vsipath)
gdal.Unlink(vsipath)
img = gimg.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

Am I going about this wrong? All I want to do is turn my 16-bit s3 .tif into a numpy array without having to download a local copy. Help!

Comment: Can you provide an example image to be able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Here's a Sentinel 2 example. You'll probably have to make an account at https://scihub.copernicus.eu... https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('285ba061-9514-4815-9bc4-55040c36240c')/$value

Comment: If you run `exiftool YOURIMAGE.TIF` and then click [edit] and paste in the output, it should be possible to tell you the answer. Failing that, the likeliest answers are a) it's a 16-bit multi-channel TIFF that PIL can't handle, or b) it is compressed with a codec you don't have installed - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71113132/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell I already know that they are 16-bit multi-channel TIFFs. The problem is they're huge and I have a lot of them. I don't want to download local copies of each one during the process of converting them to usable numpy arrays.

Comment: So you know PIL can't handle that https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: I don't understand the premise of your question. You have large 16-bit per channel TIFFs on S3 and you want to work on them without downloading them? How could that be possible?