Get image from data looking like \x00\x00\x87
How do I create/get/open the image from a URL request when the response looks like this:
\x00\x00\x00 ftypavif\x00\x00\x00\ ... \x87"y~\x13 $%\\\xad ... xb5\xa07tR\x80

Much longer, of course.
An example of such a URL is here (not my website).
Normally I do it like this:
import requests
import urllib, cStringIO, PIL, io
from PIL import Image

ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
headers = {'User-agent': ua, 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}

# below url returns regular image and code works 
imgurl = "https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_focal-860x484,f_auto,q_auto:best/MSNBC/Components/Video/201610/tdy_food_brisket_161021__142565.jpg"

# below url does NOT work.
imgurl = "https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_focal-860x484,f_avif,q_auto:eco,dpr_2/MSNBC/Components/Video/201610/tdy_food_brisket_161021__142565.jpg"

r = requests.get(imgurl, headers=None, verify=False,timeout=3)
image = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(r.content))

The error for the bad URL is "IOError: cannot identify image file ..."
I also tried
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))

and various versions of
data = bytes.fromhex(r.content)

import binascii
data = binascii.a2b_hex(r.content)

They all return various errors.
Note that I am still using Python 2.7 with PIL (Pillow).

An easier knee-jerk is "not adequately specified to be answerable". An example of a literal value is not a format specification.

...that said, are you very sure your version of PIL is compiled with AVIF support? It's a relatively modern file format; a library version built for Python 2.x may just be too old. (This is a place where trusting the .jpg extension to be meaningful may be leading you in the wrong direction; a real browser will look at the MIME type, not at the file extension).

I provide the link and URL where you can get the full value. It's over 100,000 characters long, a bit much to include here. Not sure what else you'd need. The text I included is representative of what I'm trying to solve.

Right, and that file is AVIF. Which came out in 2019. Which is way, way newer than Python 2.7. So you'd need much more modern tools.

That said, the "full value" being only behind a link and not included in the question itself means the question isn't fully specified to be answerable standing alone (questions are supposed to still make sense to readers even if all links contained within them break). If you'd said as part of the question that you were trying to parse an AVIF file instead of expecting people to follow a link and figure that out, that would be a different matter -- it'd be part of the self-contained specification.

I already did explain your problem. That you don't like that explanation doesn't make it untrue.

AVIF is not supported by PIL see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71113132/2836621

If you did provide an answer, then I guess your snarky comment of "not adequately specified to be answerable" wasn't correct... Your first and only comment could have been something like "The example that you're showing is AVIF format. I don't think that's supported by PIL for Python 2.7." Simple, helpful.

Right. The thing is, I had to make a (well-informed) guess that your response is AVIF (supported by the response header and parameters in the URL used to retrieve that response), but it's still a guess; there's no firm proof in the question itself until we go beyond scope of evidence included "in the question itself" to download and analyze the actual linked file.

Supported formats are here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#fully-supported-formats

Luckily, other people didn't require all 100,000 characters to identify it as AVIF. Knowing the format, I was able to find a solution, which I posted. Charles Duffy, If you don't know the answer, please just scroll on by and let others answer.

Turns out that the data format is AVIF. This isn't supported out of the box with PIL/PILLOW, at least not in Python 2.7.
I solved it by using pillow-avif-plugin.
After pip installing it, include
import pillow_avif

That's it. The old code then works:
image = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(r.content))



\x00\x00\x00 ftypavif…



# below url does NOT work.
imgurl = "https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_focal-860x484,f_avif,…


These are hints that the image is in AVIF format which is not supported by this version of PIL.
