how to use variables inside a u string
I'm writing a code that takes an Arabic text that contains dialects (You can think of it as special characters such as ö, å and ä) and writes it on an image. The way I found to display those dialects is by using an u string
print(u'السّلامُ عَلَيْكُم')

The thing is: I need to use arabic_reshaper and bidi.algorithm to make the program display the arabic text in the right way, therefore my text is stored as a variable and I don't know how to make the program write the variable on the image as a u string.
Here is my code:
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import sys
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

font = ImageFont.truetype('AA Sameer Qamri Regular.ttf',size=100)

text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("السَّلامٌ عليكمُ"))
print(text)


image = Image.open("insta background.png")

t1 = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
t1.text((200 ,image.height - image.height/2- 50), f"{u'{text}'}", font=font, fill =(0,0,0), font_size= 100)

image.show()

As you can see I tried to combine u and f strings but apparently that's not possible. I don't know what to do other than that.

u strings are not necessary in Python 3. All strings are now Unicode. So just use an ordinary f-string.

A normal f string won't show the dialects for some reason

It shouldn't be necessary, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string

when I write:
t1.text((200 ,image.height - image.height/2- 50), f"{u'{"السَّلامٌ"}'}", font=font, fill =(0,0,0), font_size= 100)
I get:
السلام
instead of:
السَّلامُ

You're not using a variable in there, why do you think you need an f-string?

Just use: t1.text((200 ,image.height - image.height/2- 50), "السَّلامٌ", font=font, fill =(0,0,0), font_size= 100)

oh sorry I posted the wrong line of code, it should be:
t1.text((200 ,image.height - image.height/2- 50), f"{text}", font=font, fill =(0,0,0), font_size= 100)
Here variable text is what contains what I want to write on the image

@Abdulmoty f"{u'{text}'}" will just become the string {text}. If you don't want to add anything to it, just use the text variable there.

You don't need the font_size parameter on t1.txt(...) - you set it when you loaded the font.

Are you sure those characters are in the font you loaded?

@Abdulmoty python-bido and arabic-reshaper are hacks are do not support all arabic script languages and dialects. It is best not to use them. Pillow if configured correctly doesn't need them. By default Pillow uses Raqm for rendering if it is installed. You need to install free type, harbuzz, fribidi and Raqm libraries.

@Andj I've figured out that the problem is from arabic-reshaper. In the configuration they have delete_harakat set to False by default so I had to change that and I had to set shift_harakat_position to False to get it semi-working.
I'd like to know more about Raqm and how to install and use it to make my script work probably, could you please elaborate more?

@Abdulmoty pyfribidi can be used instead of python-bidi and arabic-reshaper. Re Raqm, what operating system are you using?

You can check if you have raqm etc like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69423137/2836621

@Andj I use Windows 11

@Abdulmoty windows is complex. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545244/installing-raqm-libraqm-windows-10#answer-58645729. You'll need to uninstall pillow, make sure freetype2, fribidi and harfbuzz libraries re installed, install raqm, then reinstall pillow. Easier on Linux and macOS. Raqm is also used by mplcairo a backend for matplotlib, and by extension wordcloud, seaborne and other modules built on matplotlib.

ok thank you so much, I'll give it a try

u has not been needed since Python 2. All strings in Python 3 are Unicode. It was also only needed when you're writing a string literal, you don't need it around variables.
Just use the text variable directly.
t1.text((200 ,image.height - image.height/2- 50), text, font=font, fill =(0,0,0), font_size= 100)

If you need to substitute it into another string, just use an ordinary f-string:
t1.text((200 ,image.height - image.height/2- 50), f"The string is: {text}", font=font, fill =(0,0,0), font_size= 100)


when I use the code you provided it outputs the text without any dialects, and I want it to output the dialects too

Do you get the expected output from print(text)? If so, it sounds like a problem with PIL not being able to render that text.

@Abdulmoty what happens when you try the text at https://urdufonts.net/fonts/aa-sameer-qamri-regular ? does it have the diatritics?

Or maybe an issue with the font you're using.

No I tried the font on the website that Pete Kirkham suggested and it worked perfectly. Also when I use u string and write the text by myself (as a string not a variable) it shows the dialects just fine

I don't know what the problem is, but adding u to the string won't fix it. It's clearly something related to how PIL renders the text.

Background: Python 2 '...' literals were replaced by b'...' literals when intended to be used like binary strings, and '...' literals when used as text. u'...' literals were originally removed from Python 3 entirely as unnecessary, but were added back (in Python 3.3?) to facilitate porting old code that used u'...' literals. New code does not need to use it as all, as there is no semantic difference between '...' and u'...' in Python 3.

And even when it was required, it only applied to the literal text. It has nothing to do with variables that are substituted into a format string.

You have missing dependencies. If libraqm is installed then pillow by default uses Raqm for rendering text otherwise it falls back to its basic renderer.
